# jQuery datepicker not popping up on readonly input with iOS

Tags: jquery, ios

I have a form with a date selector input. I am using jQuery datepicker. When a user clicks on the input, the calendar pops up. I want to disable typing in the date input so the user must select from the date input. I made the input field and for everywhere except iOS, if I click on the input, the calendar pops up. On iOS, if I tap on the input, the calendar will not pop up. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this for ios?

One hacky solution that works is:

```
$("#stay-start").on("keydown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But it is not idea because you can still see the curser, which makes it seem like you *should* be able type in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#datepicker").show();
    },
    beforeShow: function() {
      $("#datepicker").hide();
    },
    onClose: function() {
      $("#datepicker").show();
    }    
    
  });
  $("#datepicker").attr("readonly", "readonly");


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmmarca/nh2sLt46/5/